# VSCode complains in jsconfig.js that node_modules/source-map/source-map can not be found

Tags: visual-studio-code

See the below error and jsconfig.json file contents:
[image: VSCode jsconfig.js error]

I have no idea what the problem is... The "source-map" file the error is referring to DOES exist at the given path.

Note, that everything works fine and as expected, so the error does not seem to cause any problems.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Run the `Developer: Reload Window` command in VSCode, or close & re-open VSCode. That solved it for me.

Comment: I tried restarting VSCode, which worked for a little bit. However, the error came back after some time...

Comment: How about removing node_modules folder from disk and re-install `npm i` (right after reloading VSCode)?



If that fails i recommend mentioning your VSCode version, operating system version, and what VSCode extensions you use in the original question. And probably add an issue with VSCode at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+source-map or see if there is one logged already.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The issue seems to be gone now... I have no idea what fixed it. Perhaps it got fixed during a recent update of VSCode. If it comes back, I'll open an issue with them. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Read this as:   `Top Menu --> View --> Command Palette -->  Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: I think it's still a bug.. Reloading is just a workaround the bug. Not the solution.

Comment: Performing this changes, fixed the error for me! [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102335#issuecomment-658008216)